# SIGAINT and Monero Tor node

Tags: tor

What is SIGAINT and why are they running a Monero node on Tor?

Has SIGAINT made a statement explaining their rationale?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is SIGAINT

From their [website](http://sigaintevyh2rzvw.onion/):

> What is SIGAINT? SIGAINT is a darknet email service that allows you to send and receive email without revealing your location or identity. We provide this service to help journalists and activists combat the dragnet surveillance that exists on the Internet today. Even if you aren't in conflict with the state or anyone in particular you as a human being deserve privacy.

In addition, there is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGAINT) Wikipedia entry.

---

> and why are they running a Monero node on Tor?

From their [announcement](http://monero7tukbkxn57.onion/):

> It enables a Tor user to easily transact in Monero using a thin-client while securely maintaining the keys to their wallet on their computer all while not even exiting Tor!

---

> Has SIGAINT made a statement explaining their rationale?

Yes, they have:

> **Why Monero?**
>
> The [SIGAINT](http://sigaintevyh2rzvw.onion/) operators firmly believe that [Monero](https://getmonero.org) is the next logical step in Darknet commerce. It solves most of the privacy problems that plague cryptocurrency systems such as Bitcoin. [(Youtube video explaining how Monero works.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEVm1dMn5Ks)

There is one, additional, interesting bit from their [announcement](http://monero7tukbkxn57.onion/), namely:

> **What about cryptocurrency X/Y/Z? I heard they can mix/join/ninja vanish.**
>
> Bitcoin mixers (even coinjoin) are not enough to maintain transaction unlinkability. Not to mention the Bitcoin blockchain data is currently being mined and sold to law enforcement.
>
> Dash's supernodes could collude to reveal who you are.
>
> Zcash is operated by an LLC in the USA. Besides the obvious political problems, Zcash doesn't mix by default it is opt-in. Also, it may be possible for the maintainers to secretly inflate the currency by hiding inflation into zk-SNARK "pours".